# How can I query two separate non-linked SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server

My goal is to pull data from 5 tables into one resultset, using a UNION Query.

Problem is that my tables are distributed across two separate servers (SQL Server v11.0 and SQL Server v13.0). They are not linked, they cannot be linked, and they have no relationship whatsoever.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Sometimes I wish there wasn't a limit to how long a comment in StackOverflow can be. Because this answer is just NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not going to happen in 11 and 13. But if it's really just a union you need, import to a staging area using bcp or your favorite ETL tool; if staging is in one or the other servers then you can union right there and save the transfer of any duplicates that would have been removed from the union (assuming we want a union and not union all).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my environment is really weird.... I don't have access to a staging area or any real control over the databases in my organisation. I do have a SQL database with full control, but it's not SDE enabled due to licensing issues, and part of my queries are geospatial in nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can try througt ACCESS. You can connect ACCESS with ODBC to both server, do a union in ACCESS and then upload the result where you want.

But this depend on the dimensions of the table of course.

Comment: Yep, I can do it with PowerQuery too, in Excel or PowerBI. Thanks, but the question is specifically about a SQL only approach.